# IntellijIdea/PyCharm shows false syntax errors

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, ide

Recently, `PyCharm professional` started to show me errors that don't exist. It looks like it validates the syntax while I'm typing and then, after the command/variable is written, it doesn't revalidate the syntax. It do this in all projects, not just one.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, it looks like it "sees" just `STATUS_` and `STATUS_FI` instead of whole commands.

I invalidate caches and restarted the `PyCharm` but it didn't help.

Comment: That's probably https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-45776 (check **Help | Show Log in | idea.log** for the NPE). I expect 2020.3.1 with the fix to be released today.

Comment: @PavelKarateev Exactly! It was automatically fixed and I checked the version, it's new, from today. Thanks